# Lights not doing anything

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, lighting

I'm working on a project and no matter what light I put in everything stays the same. It won't even show itself unlit. Also yes the scene lighting is on. I have tried altering Pixel Light Count nothing works -100 - 100. I turned off my scriptable render pipeline too and even that didn't work.
[No lights in scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ34k.png) [Light in scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbkx7.png) [scene lighting on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHUUj.png) btw I've used this specific scriptable render pipeline before and it works but I disabled it anyway.

Comment: Is the material you use having a lit shader supporting 2D lighting?

Comment: I don't know its just sprites default

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5l8vP90EvU, try follow the setup guide in this link for 2D lights. It may be an issue with your material using the wrong shader, or a setup issue.

Answer (score 0):

My render pipeline was set in one place but not the other small problem easy fix.
Essentially go into setting and if your using HDRP make sure it says HDRP under render pipeline and then check under the lighting assets to see if HDRP is enabled.